# Prove $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{P_n(z)}{z^{n+1}(z-a)}dz=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

I've been solving problems from my Complex Analysis course, and I want to make sure if what I think what I think may be the path to solution is correct. The problem says:

> Prove that $$\int_{|z|=r}\frac{P_n(z)}{z^{n+1}(z-a)}dz=0$$ if $P_n$ is a
> polynomial of degree less or equal to $n$, and $a\in D(0,r)$.

The notation $D(0,r)$ refers to the open disk with center $0$ and radius $r$. My attemp:

Given the fact that $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree at much $n$, I've considered using Cauchy's Formula for derivatives, since this implies $(P_n(z))^{(n)}=n!$ (and it seemed to work well with Cauchy's integral formula, but now I doubt it's usefulness),  but the problem I have is that I'm unsure if this case verifies the hypothesis of the Formula. First (and blindly assuming I am able to use this formula here) I tried to use as my $f(z)$ in Cauchy's Formula $P_n(z)/(z-a)$, doing this
$$\int_{|z|=r}\frac{P_n(z)}{z^{n+1}(z-a)}dz=\int_{|z|=r}\frac{P_n(z)/(z-a)}{z^{n+1}}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{n!}\text{Ind}_{|z|=r}(0)\left(\frac{P_n}{z-a}\right)^{(n)}(0),$$
but clearly it did not work since the result is not $0$ ($\text{Ind}(0)=1$) and I believe this formula can't be used here because $P_n(z)/(z-a)$ is not holomorphic in $z=a$.
Trying the other way, to be said, using as $f(z) $ the function $P_n(z)/z^{n+1}$ does not seem useful either, and the same problem appears since it's not holomorphic in $z=0$.

Could you give me any hint on how to reorganize my expression in order to correctly use Cauchy? Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $I(r) = \int_{|z|=r}\frac{P_n(z)}{z^{n+1}(z-a)}dz$ for $r > a$. The crucial fact is that the integral does not depend on $r$, so that
$$
 I(r) =  \lim_{\rho \to \infty} I(\rho) = 0
$$
because of the limit on the degree on $P$.

The independence on $r$ follows from the residue theorem
$$ I(r) = 2 \pi i \bigl(\operatorname{Res}(f, 0) + \operatorname{Res}(f, a)\bigr)
$$
with $f(z) = \frac{P_n(z)}{z^{n+1}(z-a)}$, but also from a generalized version of Cauchy's integral theorem: If $\gamma_r$ denotes the circle with radius $r$ (in mathematically positive orientation) then
$$
  \int_{\gamma_{r_1}} f(z) \, dz =  \int_{\gamma_{r_2}} f(z) \, dz 
$$
for $a < r_1 < r_2$ because $f$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the annulus $r_1 \le |z| \le r_2$, and
$$
 \operatorname{Ind}(\gamma_{r_1} - \gamma_{r_2}, z) = 0
$$
for all $z$ with $r_1 < |z| < r_2$.

Yet another option is to calculate the integral using the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity):
$$ 
I(r) = -2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f, \infty) = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left( \frac 1z f(\frac 1z)\right)
= 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}\left( \frac{z^{n+1}P(1/z)}{1-az^2}\right) = 0
$$
because $\frac{z^{n+1}P(1/z)}{1-az^2}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Of course this is nothing but the result of substituting $z=1/w$ in the original integral.

Comment: Oh, I did not consider using Residue Theorem, I'll try it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso: You are welcome! In fact you can also use a generalized version of Cauchy's integral theorem for multiply connected regions.