# Can you use the Cauchy-Goursat theorem to evaluate a limit or is the ML theorem more suitable?

Tags: contour-integration

I am wondering how to evaluate the limit in the picture below. I've read online that the limit at infinity is zero when the denominator $\geq$ (numerator $+2$) but why is this? I am skeptical that I can use the Cauchy-Goursat theorem. Is there a way to show that the limit goes to zero using the ML inequality.

> Page 169 of the textbook says that if $|f(z)|\leq M$ For all $z$ on a (piece wise smooth) curve $C$ With length $L,$ then $\left|\int_Cf\right|\leq M\cdot L.$
> Now let $C$ be the upper half-circle $|z|=R,$ $\operatorname{Im} z>0.$ Show:
> $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_C \frac{2z^2-5}{(z^2+1)(z^2+4)}\,dz=0$$

Thanks

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4137201/42969.

Comment: I don't know anything about residues so I'm looking for a different explanation. I think the problem is asking for an ML explanation.

Comment: So what do you get when estimating the integral? The length of the curve is $2 \pi R$, and the integrand is $\sim 2/z^2$ for $z \to \infty$.

Comment: Ya that is my thinking as well, but is it that simple. That's pretty much a calculus theorem, and I don't see it relating to the ML theorem. It's 10 points which is also kinda strange

Comment: It is that simple. $M \sim 2/R^2$ and $L = 2 \pi R$.

Comment: Thank you for your help Martin.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show:
$$\begin{align}\left|2z^2-5\right|&\leq 2R^2+5\\
\left|z^2+1\right|&\geq R^2-1\\
\left|z^2+4\right|&\geq R^2-4
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

This does not require Cauchy-Goursat to estimate. Taking the extreme bounds on the contour of integration, and using that the length of the contour of integration is $\pi R$, we get for $R\gt2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\int_{\!\!\substack{|z|=R\\\mathrm{Im}(z)\ge0}\!\!}\frac{2z^2-5}{(z^2+1)(z^2+4)}\,\mathrm{d}z\,\right|
&\le\frac{2R^2+5}{\left(R^2-1\right)\left(R^2-4\right)}\,\pi R
\end{align}
$$
Finish by taking the limit as $R\to\infty$.