# Proving that $ \int_\gamma \ \frac{1}{(z - z_{1})(z - z_{2} )..(z - z_{n})} \,dz = 0 $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Suppose
$$ \displaystyle \\ R(z)=\frac{1}{(z - z_{1})(z - z_{2} )..(z - z_{n})} $$

where $ z_{1}, z_{2},...,z_{n} $ all are complex numbers.

I want to prove that

$$ \int_\gamma R(z) \,dz  = 0 $$

for every closed curve $\gamma $ that engulfs all singularities.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4137201/42969 for a similar task.

Comment: @MartinR Might be a stupid question, but how do i show that the integral doesn't depend on r?

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem? The integral depends only on the residues of $R$ at poles which are enclosed by the curve.

Comment: Another option (as I indicated in the other thread) is to substitute $z=1/w$, so that you get a new integral where all singularities of the integrand are *outside* the curve.

Comment: @MartinR I haven't made it to the chapter that goes over the residue theorem yet. I have learned that a closed curve can be deformed into another closed curve so long as R(z) is holomorphic on the new domain. Can i use this to my benefit? I was thinking that by showing that R(z) = 0 for the contour-integral |z| = R, where R is a large number, i could then use what i stated above. Or am i way off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean $n\geq 2$. In that case you may do an ML-estimate: note that $\gamma$ can be replaced by the circle $C_R$ centered at the origin with radius $R$ which is sufficiently large to enclose all $z_1, \cdots, z_n$. Then
$$\left|\int_{C_R}\frac{1}{(z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_n)}dz\right|\leq \frac{1}{|R-|z_1||\cdots|R-|z_n||}\cdot 2\pi R.$$

On the one hand, the original integral stays constant as long as $C_R$ encloses all numbers $z_1, \cdots, z_n$ by Cauchy's Theorem. On the other hand, the RHS goes to 0 as $R$ goes to infinity. It follows that the integral is 0.