# Finding the maximum value of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to show that $\int_{C_r}\frac{1}{z^3-8}dz=0$ where $C_r$ is the circle of radius $r > 2$ centered at $0$. I have been given a hint to use the fact that $|\int_{C_r}\frac{1}{z^3-8}dz|\leq \max(|\frac{1}{z^3-8}|)(\operatorname{length}(C_r))$. I know the length of $C_r$ but how do you find the maximum of the function?

Comment: Use the fact that $|\frac 1{z^3-8}| \leq \frac 1 {r^{3}-8}$

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4172757/42969.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but isn't r larger than z so it should be the other way around?

Comment: $|z^{3}-8| \geq |z^{3}|-8=r^{3}-8$.